Intel Corporation Device a780 (rev 04) - Onboard Video
Trying to get proper video card drivers installed on Ubuntu 20.04 (5.15 Kernel) for onboard Intel a780.
lspci -v | grep -A 10 VGA

VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device a780 (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0ac7
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
        Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff

Closest thing I could find:
https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/driver/client/overview.html
If I use:
apt install --install-recommends -y linux-image-intel
I get 5.15.0-1066-intel-iotg which seems to work great.
I'm on an earlier version of 5.15, just wondering if there is anything I can do to get drivers working for my current kernel version?
No matter what I try, I get -display UNCLAIMED.
any suggestions much appreciated!
thanks!

I'd like to take the configs and firmware from the 1066-intel-iotg and possibly build a new i915.ko specific to my kernel version, wondering if that would work?  Or perhaps there is a backport of the drivers that would work.  I've made many attempts, still no luck.
